# Azure connect Hybrid not syncing cloud accounts to local AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-connect

Helo all,

I am trying to setup Azure AD connect for an Enterprise. They have local active directory on "internal.theirdomain.com", with local server DNS being setup for that too.

However in their Azure AD they have some accounts already under "theirdomain.com". This active directory has 3 domains associated with it: theirdomain.com, internal.theirdomain.com and theridomain.onmicrosoft.com where the first one is the primary.

I installed the Azure AD connect and set it up on the local server handling internal.theirdomain.com and after sync this happens:

local accounts go to Azure with ".internal.theirdomain.com", but accounts in the cloud are not downloaded.
Also, upon assigning a license to the accounts uploaded their email address is sent from "@theirdomain.onmicrosoft.com" while emails sent from their cloud accounts is sent from "@theirdomain.com". Do you happen to have any ideas on how to fix these:

- have cloud accounts synced to local AD
- have default email domain be "theirdomain.com" for all accounts

The one problem I can see for now is that "internal.theirdomain.com" is not resolvable from internet. I am adding that into their internet DNS but was wondering if you have any other tips.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you mean that you want to  sync user accounts from Azure AD to Local AD?

Comment: Hello, Yes. Mainly need users be able to login into local AD network and have access to their office 365 email on outlook desktop app..

Comment: For now, Azure AD Connect does not support Syncing from Azure Active Directory to On-Premises AD . If this feature is important to you , you can upvote it in this Custom Feedback Forum:https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/6455327-sync-azure-active-directory-down-to-on-premises-ad